# Optimizing css compiler

Tags: css, optimization, compiler-construction, compression

I'd like real optimization/compilation of my CSS styles (not just minification), in a similar vein as the Google Closure Compiler works for JavaScript.

For example, if my entire stylesheet is just:

```
div#hello { 
    color: #FFF;
    background-color: #000;
}

div#hello p {
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

a {
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

That can be optimized down into (I'm keeping whitespace here for readability, but obviously that would have to go too):

```
#hello {
    color: #FFF;
    background: #000
}

#hello p, a {
    color: #FFF;
    margin: 10px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be what you are looking for:

http://iceyboard.no-ip.org/projects/css_compressor

Heres a comparison of a few others:

http://www.bloggingpro.com/archives/2006/08/17/css-optimization/

Comment: How would you compare this with CSSTidy?

Comment: The second link I sent you says icey is better than CleanCSS, which is based off of tidy. But that was 5 years ago so things may have changed. Icey is just a webpage, and tidy seems like a small download. Why don't you try both and see which compresses your code better? If compression is a major concern, you can use both.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want CSSTidy: http://csstidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How would you compare this with http://iceyboard.no-ip.org/projects/css_compressor?